# merge a list of 2 lists or use a queryset?

Tags: python, django

My models are as follows (the fields in floor and board are inconsequential and omitted)

```
class floor(models.Model):

class board(models.Model):

class run(models.Model):
    floor = models.ForeignKey(Floor)
    boards = models.ManyToManyField(Board)
```

I have a query as follows:

```
runs = Run.objects.filter(floor=1)
```

that returns 2 run objects. Each run has a selection of boards.

```
runs[0].boards
```

returns a list of related boards. If i make a comprehension as follows:

```
[run.boards.all() for run in runs]
```

I get a list of lists like this:

```
[[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
```

What is an effective and efficient way to massage the above list into the list below?

```
[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
```

I am hoping for a 1 line solution. Is this possible using methods of the django query set, or is this best accomplished using python?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simple:

```
board.objects.filter(run__floor=1)
```

Comment: you are a damned genius. but i can only get  board.objects.filter(run__floor=1) to make it happen - is this because run and board are connected via a m2m relation? i know if i have a board i can do board.run_set.all() but in the filter i cannot... can you remind me why? oh it must be because fk/m2m sets are generated as part of a queryset, while the filter arguments are direct references to fields... is that right?

Comment: @Justin that's strange behaviour, what version of Django are you using? Have you seen the backward relation documentation? http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#many-to-many-relationships

Comment: here is the explanation i was looking for: http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships
queryset.relatedobject_set vs. Model.objects.filter(relatedobject__field=x)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest method I could think of:

```
>>> all_boards=[]
>>> for boards in (run.boards.all() for run in runs):
        all_boards+=run
>>> all_boards
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

I changed the `[...]` list comprehension into a generator comprehension `(...)`.  It probably won't matter here, but for some applications you can save a lot of memory by using generators instead of building the complete list each time.

---

### An aside

You can keep the laziness going:

```
>>> l = [[1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,10]]
>>> def G(lol):
        for inner_list in lol:
            for element in inner_list:
                yield element
>>> for i in G(l):
        print(i,end=',')
1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,
>>>
```

The elements are coming out of G(), flattened, one element at a time, so you could walk over them and do your work per-element without having to build a temporary list.

Answer (score 1):

even though the question was answered in a better way, I cannot resist my itertools advocacy

```
from itertools import chain

all_boards = list(chain(*runs))
```